# CSS filter override incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I have social media icons in svg format and when I hover it, I want to change their color with filter. First time (not using :hover), filter works, i made them white. However, it does not work when i say filter again in the facebook, twitter, instagram :hover

Why is that, I could not find any reasonable explanation ?

Note: It works when I put filter to each .button as shown but did not work when I put filter to bottom-container.

```
.bottom-container {
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    /* filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%); */
    /* filter changes the color of svg file (not the empty spaces but the drawing) */
    /* get this code from hex to css filter color converter */
    margin-right: 18px;
    word-spacing: 12px;
}

.facebook {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 3.5%;
    width: 3.5%;
}

.instagram {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 3.5%;
    width: 3.5%;
}

.twitter {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 3.5%;
    width: 3.5%;
}

.facebook:hover, .twitter:hover, .instagram:hover{
    filter: invert(43%) sepia(60%) saturate(880%) hue-rotate(241deg) brightness(83%) contrast(83%);
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="bottom-container">
            <img class="facebook" src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook-img">
            <img class="twitter" src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter-img">
            <img class="instagram" src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagram-img">
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 3% 7%;
    background-color: black;
}

.bottom-container {
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    /* filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%); */
    /*When I comment out above line and comment the filter lines in .facebook .twitter .instagram, filter does not work properly*/
    margin-right: 18px;
    word-spacing: 12px;
}

.facebook {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
}

.instagram {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
}

.twitter {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg) brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
}

.facebook:hover, .twitter:hover, .instagram:hover{
    filter: invert(43%) sepia(60%) saturate(880%) hue-rotate(241deg) brightness(83%) contrast(83%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="bottom-container">
            <img class="facebook" src="https://ahmetezdesir.github.io/landing-page-component-1/images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook-img">
            <img class="twitter" src="https://ahmetezdesir.github.io/landing-page-component-1/images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter-img">
            <img class="instagram" src="https://ahmetezdesir.github.io/landing-page-component-1/images/instagram.svg" alt="instagram-img">
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you make a working snippet (use the <> icon in the editor) which shows the problem (I'm not clear what exactly has changed between your non-working and working versions).

Comment: I did it. Can you look at it ? Also made explanation on css file .bottom-container.